# Jenkins Post Build Task access jenkins environment variables like JOB_NAME

Tags: jenkins-plugins

I want to get the job details in Post Build Task plugin and pass the details to the batch/ powershell for further processing.

I am not able to access the Jenkins environment variables like JOB_NAME, JOB_ID etc.

In Post Build Plugin task

Log text "BUILD SUCCESSFUL"
OPTION

Script Block:
run.bat $JOB_NAME-$JOB_ID

I need to pass the $JOB_NAME-$JOB_ID to the script.

Answer (score 2):

Build Parameters are accesses as $Name in the Execute shell and post build section.
You can use

```
$JOB_NAME 
$BUILD_NUMBER
```

for name of job and build number which is same as JOB_ID.

Also Set "Jenkins user build variables" to get more info regarding Environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the sintax for accessing variables is the following:

```
${VARIABLE}
```

but in some cases, especially when you are trying to access variables using during the build, this sintax can be used:

```
${ENV, var="VARIABLE"}
```

That in my case is working also when you have a parameterized build.